# Reset button not updating value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pulling blanks on this, it looks like it should work, but...

I have a button:

```
 <button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" ng-click="reset()">Clear </button>
```

Condensed version of reset function:

```
  $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.application = {};
        $scope.PostDataResponse = null;
        $scope.errors = null;
        $scope.selectedApplication = null;
        $scope.application.status = true;
        $scope.application.version = 1.0;
        $scope.gridOptions.data.length = 0;
        $scope.ApplicationSettingsForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.ApplicationSettingsForm.$setUntouched();
    };
```

Input I'm trying to reset:

```
<input type="number" style="font-family: sans-serif" class="form-control" ng-model="application.version" ng-disabled="true" id="Version" name="Version" placeholder="Version..." required>
```

How it seeds when the page is first loaded:

```
    $scope.application = {};
    $scope.application.version = 1.0;
```

When the page loads I get a 1 in there, but when I click reset, it reverts to Version... instead of the expected 1.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the lines of code in your `reset()` function, might be throwing exceptions. Most probably it is likely to be `$scope.gridOptions.data.length = 0;` If this is not the case, please check the console to see if any other lines are throwing any exceptions.

If some lines in your `reset()` function throw exceptions, it is likely that the application object's version did not get set properly.

Can you try changing your code to this? I added some null checks, hoping to avoid any exceptions:

```
  $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.application = {};
        $scope.application.status = true;
        $scope.application.version = 1.0;
        $scope.PostDataResponse = null;
        $scope.errors = null;
        $scope.selectedApplication = null;
        if($scope.gridOptions && $scope.gridOptions.data) {
             $scope.gridOptions.data.length = 0;
        }
        if($scope.ApplicationSettingsForm) {
          $scope.ApplicationSettingsForm.$setPristine();
          $scope.ApplicationSettingsForm.$setUntouched();
        }
    };
```

Comment: $scope.application = {} resets the rest of the form, it needs to be in there ;) Also, this is just 1 controller with 1 scope, I'm not fancy enough with angular to get into scope inheritance yet...

Comment: Got it. If you can provide more of your code, I can take a deeper look.

Comment: I've updated my reset function to it's full state in the question.  Application.status isn't working correctly either.  Is it because I'm blowing them away with $scope.application = {}? But then how do I set the values after? Do I need an $apply somewhere in there maybe? Also, not sure who downvoted, but I restored the point.

Comment: I think I'm able to reproduce your problem. I'll update my answer with what I found!

Comment: Interesting idea, but no there no console errors.  I've fixed it at this point by change ng-model="application.version" to ng-value="application.version" .  Not 100% sure why this works as I thought ng-model did two way binding between the UI and controller & ng-value set the value of a field (ex. for a bool), I'd be interested in learning the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you have to define `$scope.application` as an object in your controller:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.application = { version: 1.0 };

   $scope.reset = function() {
     $scope.application = {};
     $scope.application.version = 1.0;
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="number" style="font-family: sans-serif" ng-model="application.version" placeholder="Version..." required>
    <button type="reset" ng-click="reset()">Clear </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter: May I know what is the reason of your downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this didn't fix it unfortunately.  I see the snippet working though, I'll update my question with the full reset function and start commenting some of the other stuff in there out on my end to try and find the problem...